# I want to update and add records using one button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
'Adding Function
Private Sub AddCustomer()
    Try
        sql = "INSERT INTO Category(catid, caname) Values('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
        ConnD()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn1)
        Dim i As Integer
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Customer Added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add Customer")
        Else
            MsgBox("Failed to add customer", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Add Customer")

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn1.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

'UpdateFunction
Private Sub UpdateCustomer()
    Try
        sql = "Update category set caname ='" & TextBox2.Text & "' where catid = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'  "
        ConnD()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn1)
        Dim i As Integer
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Customer Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update Customer")
        Else
            MsgBox("Failed to update customer", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Update Customer")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn1.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have tried to use *add* and *edit* using one button.

I wrote the button coding below.

Only the *update* parts works. Why isn't the *add* part working?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
        UpdateCustomer()
    Else
        AddCustomer()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is read about sql injection and parameterized queries.

Comment: Your Textbox1 text length is always greater than zero whether its update or save. so check with button text...

Comment: Don't forget to look about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the button1 text at run time and based on the button1 text you can update or add customer..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.Text = "Update" Then
        UpdateCustomer()
    ElseIf Button1.Text = "Save"
        AddCustomer()
    End If
End Sub
```